# Invalid WatchKit Support - Xcode 10 - iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, apple-watch, itunes-store

I'm trying to send the update of my app for ios 12 with xcode 10 GM.

But every time I finish the upload of the .ipa file after a few minutes I get an error email with this message:

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,"APP NAME" We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app. Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

Invalid WatchKit Support - The bundle contains an invalid implementation of WatchKit. The app may have been built or signed with non-compliant or pre-release tools. Visit developer.apple.com for more information.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue for me, hoping someone figures this out!

Comment: @UberJason now it works. I succesfully uplaoded the build now. Maybe the Apple review side or because my change. Now my app is in review

Comment: Awesome, mine is as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apple had forgotten to update their backend as was suspected. Resubmitted without even cleaning (changed just the version number) and it got processed.